# Exponential and power of a special bidiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Given the bidiagonal matrix
$$
\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 &  0  & 0   & \dots & 0 & 0\\
0   & a_2 & b_2 & 0   & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
0   & 0   & a_3 & b_3 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & a_{n-1} & b_{n-1} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & a_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

is there any simplified formulas for the entries of $\mathbf{A}^k$ and $\exp(\mathbf{A})$ where $k$ is any positive integer. Please suggest books or articles if possible.

Comment: Since the matrix is upper-triangular, the characteristic polynomial is immediately known; by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, the matrix itself satisfies this polynomial. So sufficiently large powers can definitely be expressed through lower powers of the matrix. What isn't obvious to me is if these are the only such relations...